# What is the difference between T& and T * const?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
T &ref = obj;
T *const ptr = &obj;
```

Is there any difference between these two declarations in C++ in terms of behavior?

I know that first one is called reference (whose members are accessed through dot (.) operator) and second one is called a pointer (whose members are access through arrow (->) operator).

But, if we consider their behavior, they both points to `obj` and will not be able to point to any object other than the one they are initialized with. We can modify the content of `obj` using both of them.

If both are same, which one is good for better coding style.

Comment: References are not pointers. This is a well discussed issue.

Comment: This is indeed a pretty vacuous question lacking substance beyond that which is extremely well-covered elsewhere. Did you perform any research at all?

Comment: Huh, I didn't VTC as duplicate — [silly banner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/155739).

Comment: @101010 - Can you be more specific on that? AFAIK, it reference is a way of hiding arrow (->) operator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The question that is pointed out to be duplicated is on a broad topic, which will probably make any question on pointer duplicate of it.

Comment: @army007: Read the previous comments; I did not VTC as duplicate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - But, your name is shown there.

Comment: @army007: Yes, I am aware of that. Click on the link in my comment where I complain about that broken behaviour of Stack Overflow's software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, beyond syntactic differences as you've identified, **not much**.

Use whichever one you like.